# Get the image source from get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have to get the image source from the code below.

```
  $thumburl = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
```

Here I'm getting

```
<img width="325" height="202" src="http://localhost/TantraProjects/Border-fall/Repo/WebApp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/film.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="film" title="film">
```

I want to get this part.

```
"http://localhost/TantraProjects/Border-fall/Repo/WebApp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/film.png"
```

How can I get the source ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want, more concise:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, $size);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

You can get the url for any thumbnail size, so its quite a useful function.

Answer (score -2):

there sir,

```
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($post->ID);
```

Comment: This will not work, you'll need an attachment ID as argument instead of the post ID you provided. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url