# How to retrieve image link (href and NOT src) in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, so i am trying to modify a wordpress widget that displays images, so that when you click on the image, it should lead to the url stated in the image's href attribute. I've been trying to make it work for a while now...with no success. Please help!

Here's what i've got:

```
<a href="THE CODE I'M MISSING">
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array( 370, 278 ) ); ?>
</a>
```

Thanks, folks!

Comment: The image doesn't have an href attribute, I suppose you mean src. Anyhow, check this out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link

Comment: I just now noticed your title, "href NOT src" would you explain what you mean by that? The image tag does not allow for the href attribute? I'm thinking perhaps you mean the attachments link, anyhow it's one of the template tags which you will find in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link

Comment: yeah, what i meant was naturally that i have the img inside an anchor... and i want to retrieve the anchor's href. but from an admin's point of view: when you upload the image to media on wordpress, it will ask you for a link url. so i thought you will probably be able to retrieve the href somehow referring to the image...

Comment: But what you say is exactly my problem! An image doesn't have an href. Only an src. So when i tried echo wp_get_attachment_link, it led to where the image is uploaded. But instead, i need it to lead to the href of the containing anchor.

Comment: I'm telling you to look for the right template tag. You have the ID, from $attachment->ID... I think this is the one you're looking for 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359382/get-the-image-source-from-get-the-post-thumbnailpost-id/14359678#14359678